# Sentry, Next.JS and digest

Tags: next.js, sentry

How can I add `error.digest` as a tag to all of reported errors?

```
scope.setTag('digest', error.digest)
```

In the `sentry.server.config.ts` and `Sentry.init` we can customize the `beforeSend` hook but I couldn't find the `error.digest` the `hint.originalException.digest` and `hint.syntheticException.digest` are `undefined`

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sentry.client.config.ts` file, you can add `beforeSend` logic to grab the digest off `hint.originalException` to `Sentry.init()` as you explained in your question.

Unfortunately, on the backend, you or the SDK cannot access the digest, except through logs, since React itself (this is not something Next.js is responsible for) is not exposing the digest, or the digest generation logic in any way.